# React native interactions freeze when running long async tasks

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

### Async functions

I have an async function that loops over links I provide and fetches them. It could be 100s of links.

```js
const fetchLinks = async (links) => {
    const results = [];
    for (link of links) {
        const res = await axios.get(link);
        results.push(res);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Running this will almost block navigating between pages.

### Android native modules

I then tried creating a native module for android using this [guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android). But this completely freezes the navigation until the process is completed, and I don't even await when calling the module.

The page is still scrollable while this is happen, just clicking on buttons or navigating is frozen.

What is the best way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably blocking the javascript thread.
Scrollview lives on the native thread and buttons on the javascript thread, that's why buttons are freezing.
I believe there's a limit to concurrent network request and that's why it's blocking the thread.
You may try to use Promise.all to run the request in parallel rather than sequentially. I'm not sure it will completely solve the problem but it should be much better.

```
const fetchLinks = async (links) => {
    const promises = links.map(link => axios.get(link));
    return Promise.all(promises);
};
```

Comment: That completely freezes the UI thread until all promises resolve. I've noticed that if I add a timeout between each fetch request, it does help, but every time it tries to fetch, the UI thread freezes. It is really odd that trying to fetch every 3 seconds would freeze the UI thread. I'm thinking of just moving to flutter, it seems much more stable.